# Preventing a function call while another function is executing

Tags: javascript

I have 2 functions. How can i stop executing SelectTD() function, when i am executing showAction() Function. Both functions are in different JS files. I tried with setting count but not working as expected. Can some one suggest me a better approach.

ScriptFile 01:

```
   function ShowAction(title, artist, genre) {
//showAction Stuff
}
```

ScriptFile 02:

```
 function SelectTD(StartIndex, EndIndex, Color) {
//SelectTD Stuff
}
```

Comment: You mean one after another?

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded, so... problem solved? Please post the complete code, including how you're calling those functions.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. You wouldn't get one function to execute while another one is running *unless* you explicitly call it, e.g., `function a() { b() }` will cause `b` to run while `a` does. Well, sort of - it's not simultaneous.

Comment: Not one after another, want to stop completely until another function execute.@SumeshTG

Comment: Well, assuming each function only has a single comment inside then I don't see any issue with this code. If you have a REAL code that actually demonstrate the issue then include it ([mcve])

Comment: Actually i have a table , i am implementing drag and drop functionality on that table. On the same table i am selecting tds by dragging only for merging cells. So when i start dragging both the functions are executing.

Comment: @Taju but they wouldn't be executed literally at the same time. One runs, then the other. As I said, this would be an XY problem - you seem to want to *not* execute a function while dragging.

Answer (score 0):

Since JS is single threaded, one function would run to its entirety and then only the control can go to any other function.

Perhaps you have an async call such as an AJAX call that indeed calls a function asynchronously but still whatever callback you give to it, that function would again run to its entirety before passing control to the next function in queue.

So the question comes, what is the exact scenario which you want to implement?

Maybe you want to control which function gets executed depending on some condition. That you can do using another function probably

```
var runTDfn = true;
if(runTDfn){
    ShowAction('Some title', 'Some artist', 'Some genre');
}
else {
    SelectTD(0, 1, 'some color');
}
```